# A generalization of projection matrices in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

[How to prove that $AB$ is a projection if $(AB)(BA)=AB$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493961/how-to-prove-that-ab-is-a-projection-if-abba-ab)

The above question was asked by me, and I found the solution by myself.

From the above problem, we can know that for $A,B\in M_n\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$, if $AB^2A$= $AB$,

we can get $$(AB)^2=AB.$$

Thus I have the following problem:

does this also hold in $\mathscr{B}(\mathcal{H})$, the algebra of bounded linear operators on Hilbert's space?

That is for any $A,B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathcal{H})$,
if $AB^2A=AB$,

can we get $$(AB)^2=AB?$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh,I also find the solution about the problem.

Let $$\mathcal{H}=l^2.$$

Let $A(x_1,x_2,\cdots)=(0,2x_1,x_2,\cdots)$ ,thus we can get  $||A||=2.$

Let $B(x_1,x_2,\cdots)=(x_2,\cdots)$ , thus we can get  $||B||=1.$

We also get $$ABBA (x_1,x_2\cdots)=(0,2x_2,x_3,\cdots)$$

and $$AB (x_1,x_2\cdots)=(0,2x_2,x_3,\cdots).$$

So for the above $A$ and $B$ , we can get $$ABBA=AB.$$

But $$(AB)^2(x_1,x_2\cdots)=(0,4x_2,x_3\cdots).$$

So for the above $A$ and $B$, we can get $$(AB)^2\ne AB.$$

Comment: Very clever!  Congratulations!

Comment: The next case to be considered is a finite von Neumann algebra.  Are you familiar with this concept?

Comment: @  Ruy     Sorry, I am not familiar with this concept.

Comment: Ok, so here is a simplified definition.  Consider a $*$-subalgebra $M\subseteq B(H)$ ("$*$" means closed under taking adjoints),  which admits a continuous linear functional $\tau:M\to \mathbb C$, such that: (1) $\tau(ab)=\tau(ba)$ (this is the trace property), (2) $\tau(a^*a)\geq0$ (positivity property), and (3) $\tau(a^*a)=0\Rightarrow a=0$ (faithfulness property). Then try to solve your problem within $M$.  To see the relevance of these hypotheses, try to prove that the shift, i.e. your operator $B$, can't be inside such an algebra.  The hint is  that  $BB^*=I$, but $B^*B\neq I$.

Comment: @ Ruy  Thanks! I know what you are talking about. For the finite von Neumann algebra, the above example may no longer fit.  So we may need to find another counterexample or give a proof if this proposition is true for the finite von Neumann algebta. But I am not familiar with the finite von Neumann algebra.